# checkbox id is getting null

Tags: visualforce, javascript

i have to disable the checkbox dynamically based on the lead and account first name. Scenario is if lead and account first name are equal the checkbox should be disabled. Here is my code

```
var firstName = '{!leaRec.FirstName}'.localeCompare('{!acc.FirstName}');
if(firstName ==0){
document.getElementById("checkid").disabled = true;
}
else {
alert('fail');
document.getElementById("checkid").disabled = false;
}

<input type = "checkbox" id = "checkid"/>
```

i am getting "cannot set property disabled of null". please help me out .

Comment: Checkbox ids are different in if block and else block. Is that correct?

Comment: sorry while pasting here i have done it wrong. but in page actually it is correct.Now i have edited the question

Answer (score 4):

If I had to guess, I'd say that you're calling your script directly (i.e. is is not run after the page loads), *and* your input element is after the script's source within the page. This will cause your code to fail, because the element *does not exist* in the DOM at the time you're trying to access it. Instead, make sure you wait for the page to be ready:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var firstName = '{!JSENCODE(leaRec.FirstName)}'.localeCompare('{!JSENCODE(acc.FirstName)}');
if(!firstName){
document.getElementById("checkid").disabled = true;
}
else {
alert('fail');
document.getElementById("checkid").disabled = false;
}})
```

Comment: yes @sfdcfox. you are right. Now i have done it through window.onload .. thanks for your input :)